# Change format of textline with notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file like this:

```
title1*desc1*filepath1*
title2*desc2*filepath2*
title3*desc3*filepath3*
```

i have multiple lines in this format and i want to replace it like this:

```
filepath1%title1%desc1%
filepath2%title2%desc2%
filepath3%title3%desc3%
```

I've been trying everything,but it looks like i cant get it work.

Thank you

Comment: `I've been trying everything` Can you show that?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a regular expression find/replace:

- find `^(.*)\*(.*)\*(.*)\*`
- replace with `\3%\1%\2`
- check *regular expression*
- click  replace all

Explanation:

- it captures arbitrary charaters (`.*`) delimited by start (`^`) or a literal star (`\*`) into capture groups `\1,\2,\3`
- the captured strings are used in different order in the replacement